# How can I implement a stopwatch with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, stopwatch

I'm trying to set up a basic stopwatch for tracking elapsed time. `Button1` should start the clock at 0, and `Button2` should stop the watch and record how many minutes and seconds have elapsed since the timer started. I have the buttons lodged on a worksheet and just need a way to calculate elapsed time. What would be the best approach?
Here is the code I have been working with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    startTime = Timer
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim finalTime As Single
    finalTime = Timer - startTime
    MsgBox Format(finalTime, "0.00")
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it displays the time elapsed only after I click `Button2`. I need a running timer on my Excel sheet.

Comment: Consider updating the screen 10 times per second or so?

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Started As Boolean
Dim myTime As Date
Sub StartTimer()
    If Not Started Then
        myTime = Time
        Started = True
    Else
        If MsgBox("Do you really want to restart?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            myTime = Time
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
    If Not Started Then
        MsgBox "The timer is stopped."
    Else
        MsgBox Format(Time - myTime, "hh:mm:ss")
        Started = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkblABsFHWc)

[link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/50601-implementing-stopwatch-excel.html)

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/50601-implementing-stopwatch-excel.html

Comment: change `myTime = myTime` to `myTime = Time` after restart msgbox

Answer (score 1):

If you need any accuracy, Excel is probably not the place to do this. But if close enough is close enough, then here's how I would do it.

In a standard module:

```
Public gbStop As Boolean
Public gdtStart As Date

Sub UpdateTime()

    Sheet1.Range("rngTimer").Value = Now - gdtStart
    DoEvents

    If Not gbStop Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "UpdateTime"
    End If

End Sub
```

In Sheet1's class module

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    gbStop = False
    gdtStart = Now
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "UpdateTime"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    gbStop = True

End Sub
```

When you click Button1, gbStop is set to false, the start time is recorded in a public variable, and the UpdateTime procedure is scheduled to run 1 second later.

One second later, UpdateTime runs and the value of the cell named rngTimer is changed to show the elapsed time between Now and the start recorded in Button1_Click. If gbStop is still False, UpdateTime schedules itself to run again in another second.

Eventually, you press Button2 which sets the public variable gbStop to True. The next time Updatetime runs, it doesn't schedule itself to run again.